# Should I reference a field id or have the actual data in the same row?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have two tables, `meetings_table` and `items_table`.

`items_table` has three columns:

```
id
item
description
```

`meetings_table` has two columns:

```
first_party
second_party
```

I want to show the names of the two parties and the item they're meeting about.  Should I add another column to `meetings_table` referencing the id of the item in `items_table`, then pull the item's name and description from there?  Or should I add two columns to `meetings_table`, item and description and just run one query that way?  Which is best in principal efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just reference the id of the item.  This way, if you need to update anything about the item, you just do it in one location and it will propagate across all queries using that data.  You almost never want to store data twice in a database.  Every once in awhile you will come across a situation where unnormalized data is acceptable, but this is the exception, not the rule.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to have an `id` for each item and add the `id` to the `meetings_table`, and query from there like

```
 SELECT * FROM meetings_table a, items_table b WHERE a.item_id=b.item_id
```

This will make `item` and `meetings` kinda independent of one another, and also saves space.